# ¿como es esto posible, usar métodos como "variables" en componentes de React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

estoy aprendiendo React pero me surgió una duda al llegar a la parte de los **PropTypes** y de los eventos del DOM y es por el hecho de definir métodos tanto normales como **estáticos** de manera que parecen una variable, me explico mejor:

en vanilla javascript un metodo normal o estático de una clase se escribe de esta manera

```
class Automovil{
    constructor(marca,color){
        this.marca = marca;
        this.color = color;
    }

    metodoNormal(){
        console.log(`la marca es ${marca} y el color es ${color}`)
    }

    static metodoEstatico(){
        console.log('este es un metodo estatico');
    }
}
```

ok. hasta este punto bien, no hay problema esto lo conoce todo el mundo pero porqué con React cambia la cosa? osea de la siguiente manera:

```
class Automovil extends Component{
    // mi duda es aqui
    handleClick = (event) => 
    console.log('hola!!')
    // y aqui
    static propTypes = {
        nombre: PropTypes.string
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>{this.props.nombre}</h1>
                <button onClick={this.handleClick}>click me!</button>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Porqué se puede asignar metodos de esa manera dentro de un componente de React?? `MyMethod = (event) => lo que sea`

sé que se puede usar `.bind(this)` para cada método en el constructor de un componente, pero en caso de no querer "bindear a cada rato" un método se usan las arrow functions.

**Para resumir mi pregunta**: esa sintaxis es unica de React?? el hecho de poder hacer `myMethod = función` dentro de una clase, y que esto mismo en vanilla JS da error, y lo mismo con los métodos estáticos, `static metodo = lo que sea` pero en vanilla JS da error `static metodo = lo que sea` tendría que ser `static metodo(){lo que sea}`

sé que esta pregunta parece un poco obvia pero es que me surge esa duda de porqué la notación cambia en React si se supone que es JavaScript prácticamente.

gracias de antemano y gracias por leer todo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lo que estás declarando en esa linea se conoce como una propiedad de clase, actualmente [se encuentra en la etapa 3 de propuesta](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields) para la especificación de ECMAScript.

#### Pero ¿Qué quiere decir esto?

Como podemos ver [en el documento de la descripción de etapas](https://tc39.github.io/process-document/) del TC39, en la etapa 3 están los **candidatos** para ser parte del estándar del lenguaje, mas no están listos para ser implementados

**¡Ey! Pero yo vine por el código**, de acuerdo pasemos al código. Tomaré tu ejemplo de como se construye actualmente una clase en JavaScript

```js
class Automovil {
  constructor(marca, color) {
    this.marca = marca;
    this.color = color;
    this.ruedas = 4;
  }

  metodoNormal() {
    console.log(`la marca es ${this.marca} y el color es ${this.color} con ${this.ruedas} ruedas`)
  }

  static metodoEstatico() {
    console.log('este es un metodo estatico');
  }
}

const llamandoMetodoEstatico = Automovil.metodoEstatico()
const carro = new Automovil('batimóvil', 'negro');
carro.metodoNormal();
```

Con los campos de clase podríamos escribirlo de esta forma:

```js
class Automovil {
  ruedas = 4;
  
  constructor(marca, color) {
    this.marca = marca;
    this.color = color;
  }

  metodoNormal() {
    console.log(`la marca es ${this.marca} y el color es ${this.color} con ${this.ruedas} ruedas`)
  }

  static metodoEstatico() {
    console.log('este es un metodo estatico');
  }
}

const llamandoMetodoEstatico = Automovil.metodoEstatico()
const carro = new Automovil('batimóvil', 'negro');
carro.metodoNormal();
```

En el anterior ejemplo activé la casilla de babel para poder transpilarlo a código JavaScript que pueda ser interpretado en todos los navegadores

> #### esa sintaxis es unica de React??

No, pero recuerda que React utiliza Babel para transpilar el código y que este pueda ser interpretado en todos los navegadores recientes

De hecho si vamos a la [página de babeljs](https://babeljs.io/) e intentamos poner el código de tu segundo ejemplo nos mostrará un error como este

> ```
> /repl: Support for the experimental syntax 'classProperties' isn't currently enabled (3:17):
> 1 | class Automovil extends Component{ 
> 2 | // mi duda es aqui > 
> 3 | handleClick = (event) => | ^ 
> 4 | console.log('hola!!') 
> 5 | // y aqui 
> 6 | static propTypes = { 
> Add @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties (https://git.io/vb4SL) to the 'plugins' section of your Babel config to enable transformation.
> ```

#### ¿Por qué lo hacen?

Al hacer esto `handleClick = (event) =>  console.log('hola!!')` estás declarando un campo de clase, porque estás asignando una *arrow function* a una constante.
Como bien dijiste para poder acceder a `this` dentro de una función en la clase podemos utilizar `.bind(this)` en el constructor, pero como sabemos las *arrow functions* toman el valor `this` del objeto del que es llamada, entonces **lo hacen para evitarse hacer `bind` de cada función en la clase.**

Comment: si, tienes razón sin duda es una funcionalidad que está en prueba ya que estaba probando el codigo en chromium y opera pero no me funcionaba a no ser que transpilara con babel, ahora con chrome si funciona todo bien tanto en vanilla js como con React, gracias por aclararme las dudas

Answer (score 1):

Creo que estás errado en algunos conceptos. Lo que pones en tu 2do ejemplo no es javascript, sino [jsx](https://facebook.github.io/jsx/), lo cual es una extensión del primero.  Sin embargo lo que mencionas sí se permite en Vanilla JS.

```js
class Automovil {
  constructor(marca, color) {
    this.marca = marca;
    this.color = color;
  }
  funcionColor = () => this.color;

  funcionMarca = (texto) => {
    const resultado = `${texto}: ${this.marca}`;
    return resultado;
  }

  static modelos = () => {
    return ['bmw', 'suzuki'];
  };

  static algunaVariable = 2;
}


console.log(Automovil.modelos());
console.log(Automovil.algunaVariable);

let bmw = new Automovil('bmw', 'negro');
console.log(bmw.funcionColor());
console.log(bmw.funcionMarca('la marca es'));
```

La función flecha es parte de JS desde la especificación ES6, así que no deberías tener problemas en usarlo [en la gran mayoría de los navegadores modernos](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Funciones/Arrow_functions#Compatibilidad_en_navegadores).

Comment: asi es Alter, tienes razón con lo de navegadores modernos, probé tu codigo en chromium y en opera que es donde normalmente desarrollo y no sirvió a menos de que transpilara con ayuda de babel, pero con google chrome  si lo ejecutó sin problemas, al parecer el malentendido de mi parte era que , ya que es una funcionalidad nueva no la conocía y al parecer, no todos los navegadores lo soportan, gracias por tu respuesta, me aclaraste las dudas